# facebook and meetup login always fail the first time

Tags: meteor

Login with facebook always fails the first time and fires this error :

```
ServiceConfiguration.ConfigError {message: "Service not configured", name: "ServiceConfiguration.ConfigError"}
```

i login normaly with the code below on button click :

```
   Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                Session.set("FBerror",true);
                throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
            }
          else{
            Session.set("FBConnected",true);
          }
        });
```

UPDATE :

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
env = process.env;

if (env.FB_ID && env.FB_SECRET) {
  console.log('Got settings for Facebook auth');
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: "facebook"
  });
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    service: "facebook",
    appId: env.FB_ID,
    secret: env.FB_SECRET
  });
}

if (env.MU_KEY && env.MU_SECRET) {
  console.log("key");
  console.log(env.MU_KEY);
  console.log('Got settings for meetup auth');
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: "meetup"
  });
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    service: "meetup",
    clientId: env.MU_KEY,
    secret: env.MU_SECRET
  });
}
});
```

i get this error when loging the first time:

```
 ccounts.LoginCancelledError {message: "Service correctly added to the current user, no need to proceed!", name: "Accounts.LoginCancelledError"}
debug.js:41 Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': Error: [Facebook login failed]
    at http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/audience/client/audience.js?2b18850d051d0b84b4d414a88668851f6b25e595:93:23
    at Accounts.oauth.tryLoginAfterPopupClosed.Accounts.callLoginMethod.userCallback (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/accounts-oauth.js?e601fdb200ebbc6aa49c1bcd52a0f898ab5eecf7:157:7)
    at http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/accounts-base.js?7c29db5c21a76726509bb6bb2a68a2b4b1ecf657:531:26
    at _.once (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:801:19)
    at Accounts.callLoginMethod.loggedInAndDataReadyCallback (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/accounts-base.js?7c29db5c21a76726509bb6bb2a68a2b4b1ecf657:628:7)
    at Meteor.bindEnvironment [as _callback] (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/meteor.js?e53378596562e8922a6369c955bab1e047fa866b:978:22)
    at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3860:12)
    at _.extend.dataVisible (http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3889:10)
    at http://genjurosama-199720.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:4718:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Comment: did you have the `Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove/insert` on the server? try to put it on a `meteor.startup(function(){})`

Comment: take a look at my update

Comment: there's something wrong with splendido accounts meld , it returns an error even when everything is okay :)

Comment: I see, open a new issue to alert splendido about this, he's pretty accessible

Answer (score 0):

here my work around :

```
if (err && (err.name != 'Accounts.LoginCancelledError')){
    throw new Meteor.Error("Logout failed");
}
else{
    Session.set("MUConnected",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue. I have not fixed it but my workaround is to go to the facebook login button and trigger a click (which will fail and would fail either way even if it was not the first click because it would complain about focus).

On template render just do:
$('#facebook-login').click()

After the first failed click which is triggered by the app it will work for the user.